# not able to select a dropdown option in playwright using selectOption

Tags: javascript, dropdown, playwright

I am trying to select a dropdown option from my project creation using selectOption but for some reason playwright stops with error message

my dom structure looks like this:

[image]

this is how I am calling the selectOption:

```
page.locator(//select[@class='ed-select']).selectOption('0.3333')
```

this is the error message I am getting:

```
 locator resolved to <select id="" required="" aria-label="" class="ed-select">…</select>
    selecting specified option(s)
    did not find some options - waiting...
```

I am not sure where am I getting it wrong.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This works fine for me, although I wouldn't use XPath to select that, and your syntax is wrong as shown here--you'll need strings around the XPath. `page.locator("select.ed-select").selectOption("0.3333")` would be better. Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] with the actual website to get help. Thanks.

Comment: yes I am using double quotes, just wrote it wrong out here. but it doesnt choose for some reason

Comment: Please [edit] your post to fix the problem, and, as mentioned, share the actual site so the problem is reproducible. Your code works fine for me on my end, tested with a simple script. Thanks.

Comment: Please check that this class name is unique, and this element isn't inside an iFrame or Shadow Tree.

Comment: the class name is unique, as you can see in the error message, it is able to identify but just not selecting the options

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the field was not interactable unless it clicked elsewhere and accessed again.
It seems to be an issue with the application itself.
Thank you all for helping me solve this.